# Evenly distributed chunks javascript

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have array:

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

I want to split above array into N smaller evenly chunk arrays if

```
N = 2 => ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'j'], ['b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'i'] 
N = 3 => ['a', 'd', 'g', 'j'], ['b', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'i']
N = 4 => ['a', 'e', 'i'], ['b', 'f', 'j'], ['c', 'g'], ['d', 'h']
```

How could I achieve that and get over 0(n) complexity?

Comment: Please show us what attempts you have made to solve this issue on your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a JS array into N arrays](//stackoverflow.com/q/8188548)

Comment: @4castle: It's not

Comment: @TelvinNguyen What's different about it?

Comment: @4castle: The order of the items inside of each chunk is the matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Dan O was after this:

```js
const input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
const n = 3;
const result = input.reduce((result, item, itemIndex) => {
  result[itemIndex % n] = (result[itemIndex % n] || []).concat(item);

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

But a more efficient one - O(n) would be:

```js
const input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
const n = 3;
const result = input.reduce((result, item, itemIndex) => {
  var idx = itemIndex % n;
  if (!result[idx])
    result[idx] = [];
  result[idx].push(item);
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

O(n):

```
const input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
const n = 3;
const result = input.reduce((result, item, itemIndex) => {
  result[itemIndex % n] = (result[itemIndex % n] || []).concat(item);

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This has a wrong output.

Comment: aw man where did my extra `% n` go?  edited.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that takes the original array and the number of chunks you want as parameters. The key to its success is the use of `modulo` to determine which index of the returnArray to place the element into.

```js
var origArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

function evenChunk(chunks, inputArr) {
  var returnArray = [];
  // cycle through out inputArr progressively filling each returnArray array
  for (var x = 0, len = inputArr.length; x < len; x++) {
    var selectedIndex = x % chunks; // find the expected index
    // if the index is undefined, instantiate it
    if (!returnArray[selectedIndex]){
      returnArray[selectedIndex] = [];
    }
    // push the array element at the modulo position of x onto the selectedIndex array
    returnArray[selectedIndex].push(inputArr[x]);
  }
  return returnArray;
}

console.log(evenChunk(2, origArr));
console.log(evenChunk(3, origArr));
console.log(evenChunk(4, origArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: Iterating through every item is not what I'm looking for. Thank for your help anyway.

Comment: @TelvinNguyen The algorithm in this answer is identical to the selected answer. `reduce` iterates through every item.

Comment: @4castle They look the same, but from my test the performance of the selected answer (2nd method) has better efficiency. (400-900 vs 600-1k2 ms of this answer for sample test of N =3/4/5). Personally I do not have any expert to tell which is really better or maybe I was wrong, but I'm just looking at the my practical test.

Comment: @TelvinNguyen Try changing the `if` statement in this answer to `if (!returnArray[selectedIndex])`

Comment: The output has been improved, its around 500-850ms for N=5.

Comment: @4castle, i will update my answer to include your suggested performance improvements

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var test = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];

function chunkArray(array, n) {
  if(n === 1) return array;
  return array.reduce(function(result, item, index) {
    result[index%n] = (result[index%n] || []).concat(item);
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(chunkArray(test, 1));
console.log(chunkArray(test, 2));
console.log(chunkArray(test, 3));
console.log(chunkArray(test, 4));
console.log(chunkArray(test, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this problem. This is a sequential bag-filler. If you want to put in a function the first two lines are parameters and last line is return.

```js
    var a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
    var n = 3; // n is number of blocks
    
    var l = a.length; var v = Math.floor(l/n);
    var c = 0; var i = -1; var r = []; var p = [];
 
    while(true){
      i=i+1; if (i==l) {
        r[r.length-1] = r[r.length-1].concat(p);
        break;
      }
      p.push(a[i]);
      c=c+1;
      if (c==v){
        r = r.concat([p]);
        p=[]; c=0;
      }
    }
    
    console.log(r); // r is the result
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];

function split(arr, N) {
  var counter = 1;
  return arr.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    if(counter > N) counter = 1;
    if(!obj[counter]) obj[counter] = [];
    obj[counter].push(item);
    counter++
    return obj;
  }, [])
};

var result = split(arr, 4);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this it's simply a function that accepts the array to be splitted and returns an array of evenly distributed arrays without having to set the num of elements manually.

```
    var splitArr = function (arr) {
    var numOfElements = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(arr.length));
    var newArr = [];
     while (arr.length > 0) {
       newArr.push(arr.splice(0,numOfElements))
     }
     return newArr;
   }

console.log(splitArr(arr));
```